# Multiple build operations failed

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am very much asking for help. I have been struggling with this problem for several months. I am trying to perform various methods that I found on the Internet and nothing helps. I always get this error:

```
Multiple build operations failed.
    Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    Could not create task ':google_mobile_ads:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    Could not create task ':path_provider_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    Could not create task ':shared_preferences_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    Could not create task ':url_launcher_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    Could not create task ':webview_flutter_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
this and base files have different roots: D:\Android\aplikacje\aplikacja pod domena\app-j-pl\app\Source File V_3.0.5\flyweb\build\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle and C:\Users\atom\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.17\android.
```

The application was bought on CodeCanYon, but the author does not help.

When I run the flutter version application it turns on the emulator and the application displays fine.

When I open the Android folder in Android Studio the above error appears.

Here's what I tried to do:

1. deleted the content C:\Users\atom\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache
2. Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Clean | Terminal -> flutter pub cache repair and Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Pub Get
3. .\gradlew clean Error: BUILD FAILED in 3s 1 actionable task: 1 executed

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with the Android Lifecycle Package.

check your pubspec.yaml file for this package:

```
flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:
```

Remove the line and Run (1 after another)

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub add flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle
flutter pub get
```

This should reinstall the package.
Don't know if itll solve the problem though.

If it doesnt help try searching your entire for the entire root path thats apparently different. If you find anything check if its set up correct or post the details here.

Comment: There is no flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle in my file
Can you take a look at my file?
Below I give the contents of my file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it looks like this:
I don't know which line to delete from here. I will ask for your advice.

```
name: flyweb
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.1 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  #BASE
  nb_utils: ^5.0.8
  google_fonts: ^5.0.0

  #UI
  cached_network_image: ^3.3.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.2.0
  package_info_plus: ^4.0.2
  flutter_speed_dial: ^7.0.0
  stylish_bottom_bar: ^1.0.3
  page_transition: ^2.0.9

  #STORAGE & PERMISSION
  permission_handler: ^10.3.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.15
  provider: ^6.0.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.0

  #CONNECTIVITY
  http: ^1.0.0
  share_plus: ^7.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.1.11
  store_redirect: ^2.0.1
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.6

  #Firebase
  firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.7.4+2
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.0
  firebase_core: ^2.12.0

  #PUSH NOTIFICATION
  onesignal_flutter: ^5.0.1

  #ADS
  google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0
  #facebook_audience_network: ^1.0.1

  #WEB TOOLS
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.7.2+3

  # TOOLS
  android_path_provider: ^0.3.0
  restart_app: ^1.2.1
  launch_review: ^3.0.1
  device_info_plus: ^9.0.3
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0
  global_configuration: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.1
  mobile_scanner: ^3.4.1
  app_links: ^3.4.5

  # MAP
  location: ^5.0.3 #^4.4.0
  geolocator: ^9.0.2 #^10.1.0

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0
  http: ^1.0.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true


  assets:
    - assets/img/
    - assets/img/flag/
    - assets/cfg/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).